# How to keep local SQLite database synced with ONLY that user specific data from server database

Tags: android, sqlite, rest

I am working on an android app that is talking to a REST API and the REST talks to a database. The app also has a local SQLite database. From the larger server database I want ONLY the data specific to that user to get synced to local SQLite database. It is also possible that user A has generated some content that is related to user B. In that case that specific data of user A should also gets synced to User B's local SQLite database.

**I am thinking of one of the two approaches -**

A) User creates some data (e.g. registers itself), the data first gets saved to local SQLite database and then push the data through REST to server database. Finally the server sends a status of successful saving of data.

B) User creates some data, that is sent through REST to server database. The REST sends back that data along with additional information to app to store it in local database. The app finally notifies the server of success/failure.

Since the app is going to be a serious product, I would appreciate experienced developers' opinions on most optimum approach keeping lesser network dependency and other production based constraints in mind.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know what did you choose to do in order to solve this predicament, I'm facing a very similar issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement I would suggest you to use [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) . With the use of sync adapter you can perform both manual and automatic periodic sync .

Comment: I wrote my own Sync routines for three data intensive apps, and wish I had used the Sync Adapter it would have save time and money